# make custom navigationbar titleview

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, navigationitem, titleview

I have a custom view for my navigation bar title, which I am setting like this:

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomTitleView.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView  = titleView;
```

This works as expected on the simulator but doesnt show up when testing on a device.

Any help much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the case of the file name? the simulator is case insensitive, the device is case sensitive for file names

Comment: Thank you wattson!! I cant believe I've never run into that error before.